# How to connect to Azure AD MSI extension inside from a windows container

Tags: windows-container, azure-managed-identity

I am running a web API inside windows container on a VM, Its need to communicate to Azure Key-Vault through Azure AD MSI Extension ( which already installed on VM where Container has been created )

I tied various ways to access it through

- http://HOST_MACHINE IP:50432/oauth2/token
- http://DEFAULT GATEWay IP:50432/oauth2/token
- http://localhost:50432/oauth2/token
  etc..

But I am always getting the error " Unable to connect to the remote server
"

So Is it possible to get MSI extension access from a container and what I need to do if I want to communicate on port 50432 of the host system from a container?

Comment: MSI is bound to `localhost:50342` on host, it's accessible only from within host itself since it's non routable IP

Comment: Try changing to different network type in your container and see if you can access 127.0.0.1 IP address on host (e.g. Transparent or L2Bridge)

Answer (score 0):

The Azure AD MSI Extension is now end of life, information on the deprecation is here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-ad-managed-service-identity-updates/. Tokens should now be retrieved through the Instance Metadata Service (IMDS) endpoint at http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token from within the VM.